# Restoring Default Google Cloud Service Accounts?

Tags: default, google-compute-engine, service-accounts

I believe one of our developers inadvertently deleted the two default service accounts that came with the Google Cloud Project

I am now unable to start or spin up any new servers as I receive this:

> The user does not have access to service account
>   '215988481317-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com'

Is there a way to restore this service account with the correct permissions?

OR is the entire project screwed because this account doesn't exist anymore and creating a new account doesn't have this same syntax?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the service account's project permission may have been deleted rather than the account itself. Try adding the service account email address as member with the "Editor" role [using the Permissions page](https://console.cloud.google.com/permissions?project=_).

Comment: That doesn't work.. It says it can't find the user.. as it is looking for a gmail account it looks like.